# Serving files concurrently to multiple clients in node

Tags: node.js, stream

I'm building a simple HTTP server that serves a fairly large file to clients using streams. I need to serve multiple clients at the same time, and I'm wondering what the simplest way to achieve that is.

My initial feeling is that using the `cluster` module and forking {num CPUs} processes might be the simplest way.

```
var StreamBrake = require('streambrake');
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  var stream = fs.createReadStream('/data/somefile');
  stream.pipe(new StreamBrake(10240)).pipe(res);
});

server.listen(1234, 10);
```

**Edit**: To clarify, the issue is that this code won't begin to serve the second client until it has finished serving the first.

Comment: Curious to see answers, I've wondered about this for streaming podcast audio. Ideally you could buffer parts of the file that multiple people are receiving simultaneously with a single `fs` call.

Comment: Can you define "fairly large".  I guess what I'm really getting at is, is there any reason you can't cache this file?

Comment: The entire issue was caused by a strange problem where Chrome doesn't make a second `localhost` connection while the first one is still waiting – anyone know how to prevent that? (Safari for example is fine, as is `curl`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thinking about your issue, I'm confused as to why you believe there's an issue.  CreateReadStream is asynchronous.  Here is in example that complicates the code a little bit in order to demonstrate that using CreateReadStream we can indeed service multiple connections at a time.

```
/*jshint node:true*/
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var activeRequests = 0;
var launchFiveRequests = 5;

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    activeRequests++;

    console.log('Request received');

    var readStream = fs.createReadStream('play.js', {'bufferSize': 1024});

    readStream.setEncoding('utf8');

    readStream.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(activeRequests);
        res.write(data);
    });

    readStream.on('end', function () {
        res.end();
        console.log('end');
        activeRequests--;
    });

}).listen(8080);

var options = {
    hostname: 'localhost',
    port: 8080,
    path: '/'
};

while(launchTenRequests--) {
    http.get(options, function(res) {
        console.log('response received');
    });
}
```

Serving up a sufficiently large file, and you should see that all 5 requests are live at once, and all end up ending relatively simultaneously.

Comment: There's also no problem with my code. The entire issue was caused by a strange problem where Chrome doesn't make a second `localhost` connection while the first one is still waiting – anyone know how to prevent that? (Safari for example is fine, as is `curl`).